# Semidefinite Programming

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve a numerical optimization problem using semi-definite programming. Is there a package or add-on that equips mathematica with this functionality?

Comment: A couple of links that may help.  Solving Semidefinite Programs in Mathematica (1996) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.6227.  Semidefinite programming in Mathematica using CVXOPT: http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/03/semidefinite-programming-in-mathematica.html  The 2nd from Yaroslav Bulatov, looks like it has some downloadable packages.

Answer (score 3):

Semidefinite programming (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemidefiniteOptimization.html)) has been added to Mathematica 12. Example

```
(*Dimension of matrices*)
d = 5;
(*Create matrices a0,a1,a2*)
a0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}];
a0 = a0.Transpose@a0;
a1 = IdentityMatrix@d;
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d];
a2 = TensorProduct[v, v];
a = {a0, a1, a2};
(*Vector c on objective function f = c.x*)
c = {3, 1};
(*Compute solution*)
sol = SemidefiniteOptimization[c, a];
(*Check solution*)
A = a0 + sol.{a1, a2};
ev = Sort@Eigenvalues@A;
q = PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ@A;
Print["Minimizer {x1,x2} of c.x such that A = a0+x1*a1+x2*a2 is \
positive semidefinite: \n\t", sol, "\nEigenvalues of A: \n\t", ev, "\n\
Is A positive semidefinite?\n\t", q]
```

[image]