# Packages for Semidefinite programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization, version-9

This question has already been asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7168/1532). I am not sure, whether I should have asked this question as a comment of an old question or in the general programming forum of stackexchange. Moderators please read and take appropriate decisions.

My machine is of 32 bit with `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have managed to install `cvxopt`, and necessary libraries for 64 bit (as much possible with Ubuntu). While installing `pythonika`, I am having trouble with the library, even after installing Python 2.6 and necessary interface (which, as a matter of fact loaded a lot of garbage programs - as it seems). (If someone interested, here is the error message given below). As a result, I can not install further programs. I use *Mathematica* 9.0, though I have backup of `7.0` and `8.0` as well.

The problem I am working is optimizing product of a Hermitian matrix (given) and  a positive semi-definite operator with unit trace. I am not particularly interested in graph-theoretic or other aspects of SDP. Is there any ready-made package  available which can be implemented directly. Or in worst case, is there any other programme interface which can be used in *Mathematica* 9 along with my system configuration).

I know that there are packages in Matlab for solving SDP. However, so far all of my programmes are written in *Mathematica*. I do not have time to learn Matlab and migrate all those programmes in it.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux/CompilerAdditions/libML32i3.a(mlnumenv.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'fmod@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366401) and [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/147140?p_p_auth=6bJVyoxa) (search for "cvx").

Comment: DO you have maybe a very small example you could post? Mathematica input and some indication of the desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This add-on is the best I've found:
https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC

The documentation that is more specific to SDPs is here:
http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOCUMENTATION/index.html#SemidefiniteProgramming

Answer (score 7):

Semidefinite programming (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemidefiniteOptimization.html)) has been added to Mathematica 12. Example

```
(*Dimension of matrices*)
d = 5;
(*Create matrices a0,a1,a2*)
a0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}];
a0 = a0.Transpose@a0;
a1 = IdentityMatrix@d;
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d];
a2 = TensorProduct[v, v];
a = {a0, a1, a2};
(*Vector c on objective function f = c.x*)
c = {3, 1};
(*Compute solution*)
sol = SemidefiniteOptimization[c, a];
(*Check solution*)
A = a0 + sol.{a1, a2};
ev = Sort@Eigenvalues@A;
q = PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ@A;
Print["Minimizer {x1,x2} of c.x such that A = a0+x1*a1+x2*a2 is \
positive semidefinite: \n\t", sol, "\nEigenvalues of A: \n\t", ev, "\n\
Is A positive semidefinite?\n\t", q]
```

[image]